# How to configure WebSphere Portal, IBM Watson and IBM Connections with ADFS?

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson, adfs, websphere-portal, ibm-connections

We have a ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) system. In addition, we have a WebSphere Portal, IBM Connections  and an IBM Watson system. Can anyone let me know how to configure WebSphere Portal, IBM Connections and IBM Watson with ADFS ? I am hardly getting any proper documentation to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For both WebSphere Portal and IBM Connections it's possible to use ADFS for SSO (links included below to documentation).  As for the IBM Watson, what specific product of the Watson brand do you have?

IBM Connections - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/secure/t_sec_config_saml_for_adfs.html

WebSphere Portal - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/dev-portlet/outbhttp_auth_est_sso_adfs.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to know does it provide SSL support ? As far as what I read , it does'nt provide support for SSL . I need SSL configuration also for this.

Comment: IBM Watson version is 3.5

Comment: Hi not really sure what you mean by "I need to know does it provide SSL support?".  Do you need the connection to ADFS to be through SSL?  or are you referring to the connection to IBM Connections or WebSphere Portal?

Comment: I meant all the sites and application which are there are accessed using https. Is there any configuration related to SSL or https which needs to be incorporated for SSO Connection for Portal, Watson and connections ?

Comment: I can't say for Watson, but both Portal and Connections have ways to make sure connections are secure.  By default Portal 8.5 uses port 10042 as the secure port and Connections uses port 9443.  What is typically done is use the WebSphere web server plugins on a webserver to act as a proxy so that you can use port 443.  The web server plugin should be bundled with your Portal and Connections licenses and so should IBM HTTP server.

Comment: Here is a link that shows Typical topology diagram for Portal: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/install/rm_test.html#roadmap_standalone

Hope that helps.